# Route EC2 IP to custom Route 53 domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 instance with two apps running on it -

1. NodeJS backend on port 3001
2. React frontend on port 3000

I was using the Elastic IPv4 address provided by EC2 to run both my apps like below -
Example, `192.0.0.235:3001` and `192.0.0.235:3000`.

I've purchased a domain (eg, mydomain.com) from Route 53 and I want it to route to this IP.
I create an A record and add this IP in the value.

Now, when I try to access this domain, I still have to pass in the PORT as `mydomain.com:3000`.

How do I pass in the port or configure it in some other way that the domain itself should work?

Comment: DNS does not route anything. DNS is a translation service: IP <-> HOSTNAME. Except for specialize resource records, port numbers are not a factor. The **route** in Route 53 does not mean route, it means the interstate/highway system meaning the Internet. Therefore, Route 53 is not a factor in the client specifying TCP port numbers to connect to your site. Your problem is typically managed by load balancers and proxies.

Answer (score 3):

DNS only converts a name to an IP address. Routing to ports is outside of DNS.

If you do not want to include the port in a URL, you will need to run a web server on port 80 and/or port 443 that redirects to the other port.

Or, you could run a Load Balancer that can forward traffic to specific servers and ports (extra charges apply).

Comment: Can you share some references on how to setup nginx server in EC2 instance and configure ports?

Comment: [Nginx: How do I forward an HTTP request to another port?](https://serverfault.com/q/536576)